# Update a Quarto report based on select box choice

Tags: r, shiny, quarto

My goal is to create a Quarto report that changes based on the information chosen from a select box. I'm not sure how to pass the selected information to the Quarto report.

This is what I've done so far...

````
```{r input, echo=FALSE}
selectizeInput(# create the two select boxes
  "select_lea",
  label = "District",
  choices = c("Not Selected"),
  multiple = FALSE,
  options = list(plugins = list('remove_button'))
)
selectizeInput(
  "select_school",
  label = "School",
  choices = c("Not Selected"),
  multiple = FALSE,
  options = list(plugins = list('remove_button'))
)
```

```{r server, echo=FALSE}
#| context: server
not_sel <- "Not Selected"

updateSelectInput(# update the second box based on the 1st select box
  inputId = "select_lea",
  choices = c(not_sel,sort(unique(school_profile$lea)))
)
updateSelectInput(
  inputId = "select_school",
  choices = c(not_sel,sort(unique(school_profile$school)))
)

profile_data_filtered <- reactiveVal(school_profile)

toListen <- reactive({
 list(input$select_lea,
      input$select_school)
})

observeEvent(toListen(), {
 school_profile %>% profile_data_filtered()
 if (input$select_lea != "Not Selected") {
   profile_data_filtered() %>% filter(input$select_lea %in% profile_data_filtered()$lea) %>% profile_data_filtered()
 }
 if (input$select_school != "Not Selected") {
   profile_data_filtered() %>% filter(input$select_school %in% profile_data_filtered()$school) %>% profile_data_filtered()
 }
})

observeEvent(profile_data_filtered(),{# render the filtered data
  if(profile_data_filtered() %>%  nrow() == 1){
    output$district <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$lea)
    output$school <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$school)
    output$street <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$street)
    output$city <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$city)
    output$zip <- renderText(as.character(profile_data_filtered()$zip))
    output$charter <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$charter)
    output$low_grade <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$low_grade)
    output$high_grade <- renderText(profile_data_filtered()$high_grade)
    output$students <- renderText(round(as.numeric(profile_data_filtered()$num_enrolled), 0) )
  }
})
```

```{r details, echo=FALSE}
district <- verbatimTextOutput("district") # create objects from the filtered dataset
school <- verbatimTextOutput("school")
street <- verbatimTextOutput("street")
city <- verbatimTextOutput("city")
zip <- verbatimTextOutput("zip")
charter <- verbatimTextOutput("charter")
low_grade <- verbatimTextOutput("low_grade")
high_grade <- verbatimTextOutput("high_grade")
students <- verbatimTextOutput("students")
```
````

## Below begins the report...

### `r school`

##### School Details # populate the report with the objects

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| School | `r school` |
| District | `r district` |
| Address | `r street` |
|  | `r city`, `r zip` |
| Charter | `r charter` |
| Lowest grade | `r low_grade` |
| Highest grade | `r high_grade` |
| Students enrolled | `r students` |

I'm stuck because my process doesn't populate the report. Any suggestions?